# UBUNTU - ld cannot find the library

Tags: c, ubuntu, fortran, linker-errors, ld

I am trying to compile a code which is in C and Fortran, use ccmake to create a makefile. And use GNU fortran (gfortran) and (gcc) to compile the code. At the end of compiling when it starts linking executable I get the following error:

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lFALSE

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Would anyone let me know what library is missing? what is this FALSE library which cannot be found?

How can I install it in Ubuntu?

Comment: Looks more like an incorrect expansion of some variable in the Makefile. That is, it should be `-lfoobar` where `foobar` is an optional/configured library. But for some reason the expansion resulted in `-lFALSE` instead. But that's just a guess as there really isn't enough info to say for sure. Provide the full compile command that causes that error and also the relevant Makefile(s).

Comment: It looks like `ccmake` tried to find for a library and set the library name to FALSE for those that it cannot find. Look for messages from `ccmake`.